# Underlying data structure causing all models to break, "isSingular"

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

It seems like there's some underlying structure issue in my data that's causing all my models to break. I tried using a linear mixed effects models in nlme, lmer, and repeated measures anovas. Every time, I run into some variation of the 'model is singular' error:

### Linear Mixed Effects Model (nlme):

```r
lme.totalmoss3 <-lme(moss_TOT ~permafrost*year, data = veg1,
    random =  ~ 1 | plot, method="REML", na.action = na.omit)
intervals(lme.totalmoss3) Approximate 95% confidence intervals
```

```
    Approximate 95% confidence intervals
           Fixed effects:     lower      est.     upper
(Intercept)               -1.582048  3.783333  9.148714
permafrostNOICE          -10.670785 -1.928788  6.813209
year2021                  14.920823 22.535000 30.149177
permafrostNOICE:year2021  -2.574414  9.788636 22.151687
    
    Random Effects:
    Level: plot
                        lower          est.         upper
sd((Intercept))  3.564458e-55   0.001182198   3.92091e+48

    Within-group standard error:
               lower      est.     upper
            9.202664 11.112724 13.419226
```

Breaking, assumed this was a power issue so switched to anovas

### Linear Mixed Effects Model (lmer):

```r
lme.totalmoss3 <-lmer(moss_TOT ~permafrost *year + (1 | plot),
   data = veg1, REML = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

### Repeated Measures Anova:

```r
aov.totalmoss3 <-aov(moss_TOT ~permafrost *year+
        Error(plot/(permafrost *year)), data = veg1)
```

> Warning message: In aov(moss_TOT  ~ permafrost  * year + Error(plot/permafrost  * year),  : Error() model is singular

### (different way):

```r
aov.totalmoss3 <-anova_test(data = veg1,
    dv = moss_TOT,
    wid = plot,
    within = c(permafrost, year),
    effect.size = 'pes')
```

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

As you can see, I'm looking at the effect of permafrost presence (ice, no ice) and year (2015, 2021) on total moss % cover values. Unfortunately I can't include my datasheet since the data is confidential. But here are the column headings:

[image]

Additional info:

[output for summary(lme.totalmoss3$data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zybh.png)

[screenshot of my data. 68 rows in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxNw0.png)

> > summary(lme.totalmoss3$data)   unique_id             plot                year           time         water        Length:68          Length:68
> > Min.   :2015   Min.   :1.0   Min.   : 0.00    Class :character   Class
> > :character   1st Qu.:2015   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.: 0.00    Mode
> > :character   Mode  :character   Median :2018   Median :1.5   Median :
> > 0.00
> > Mean   :2018   Mean   :1.5   Mean   : 0.77
> > 3rd Qu.:2021   3rd Qu.:2.0   3rd Qu.: 0.00
> > Max.   :2022   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :23.00
> > bare            sphagnum       cerat_pohlia     feathermoss      other_moss_sp     Min.   :  0.000   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 0.000
> > Min.   : 0.0000   Min.   : 0.000    1st Qu.:  5.287   1st Qu.: 0.000
> > 1st Qu.: 0.475   1st Qu.: 0.0000   1st Qu.: 0.000    Median : 62.335
> > Median : 0.000   Median : 3.730   Median : 0.0000   Median : 0.000
> > Mean   : 56.830   Mean   : 1.092   Mean   :12.520   Mean   : 0.8062
> > Mean   : 1.644    3rd Qu.:100.525   3rd Qu.: 0.000   3rd Qu.:20.927
> > 3rd Qu.: 0.0000   3rd Qu.: 0.595    Max.   :191.200   Max.   :41.000
> > Max.   :58.150   Max.   :15.0000   Max.   :30.540
> > moss_TOT       sp_richness     permafrost        permafrost_time     Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :0.000   Length:68          Length:68
> > 1st Qu.: 0.675   1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character   Class :character
> > Median : 9.300   Median :1.000   Mode  :character   Mode  :character
> > Mean   :16.015   Mean   :1.529
> > 3rd Qu.:28.270   3rd Qu.:2.000
> > Max.   :66.620   Max.   :3.000
> > region           ecoregion          Length:68          Length:68           Class :character   Class :character    Mode  :character   Mode
> > :character

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not surprising that you're getting similar problems with all the different methods you're trying. This is telling you that, essentially, the observed between-group variation is *smaller* than you would expect based only on the observed within-group variation, so the estimate of the variance goes to zero. Have you read the `?isSingular` help page, or the relevant section in the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1) ?

Comment: How many plots do you have? Can you show us a *picture* of your data?

Comment: Hello @Ben Bolkner, thank you for your response! the GLMM FAQ is a great resource. I have 34 plots (each duplicated across two timepoints, so 68 data points in total). I am able to share a screenshot of a subset of the data, I'll include it in this comment:

Comment: I was not able to paste the screenshot into this comment, so I put it on the question itself (at the bottom).

Comment: screenshots of data aren't too useful; you could your question to include the (textual) output of `summary(lme.totalmoss3$data)`, but I don't think that will tell us too much; I suspect in this case that you simply have a model where the observed within-group variation is large enough that it implies that you don't need a random-effects term at all. (I could be slightly surer of this if I had a *reproducible* example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @BenBolker I'm beginning to suspect the same, thank you for your help! Since I only have two timepoints, I don't have enough temporal replication to do a repeated measures model. My question now is: could I build a linear model using permafrost presence (two levels) and time (two years) as crossed fixed variables? Even though I have a repeated design?

Comment: @BenBolker The alternative a colleague suggested would be building two separate linear models (one for each timepoint) and looking at permafrost presence/absence in each. That way, I wouldn't be able to compare across timepoints though... I'll attach the output of the summary function to my post above, but, it's misleading (ex: it gives an average for my timepoints when in reality I only have two). I haven't gotten cleared to post my data, so unfortunately I can't make a reproducible answer:(

Comment: screenshots are in 'additional info' Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'm going to repeat my statement above, **screenshots of data aren't too useful** - that goes for summaries too.  Could you please include the information in your question in a text format?

Comment: @BenBolker yes, how's that? I added the summary in text format

Comment: @BenBolker sorry to pester you, I haven't found anyone else with answers on this subject! If my random effects term is proving insignificant, can I build a simple linear model with permafrost and year as fixed variables (no random effect) even though I have a repeated design, and not worry about pseudo-replication? Please let me know if I can provide any more info

Comment: I'm voting to close this & migrate it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com); the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-fits) answers this question too.